# Communication sample for SMTP over TLS (known as SSL/TLS)

Tags: communication, sample, tls1.3, smtps, smtp-server

I am trying to implement SSL/TLS im my SMTP server (PHP). Securing the connection with TLSv1.3 works, and the certificate (LetsEncrypt) is valid. I tested this with https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver where it only works when I activate 'Direct TLS':

```
 seconds        test stage and result
[000.000]       Trying TLS on mrs.dzir.org[212.58.86.63:465] (-1)
[000.100]       Server answered
[000.707]       Connection converted to SSL
                SSLVersion in use: TLSv1_3
                Cipher in use: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
                Perfect Forward Secrecy: yes
                Session Algorithm in use: Curve X25519 DHE(253 bits)
[001.185]       TLS successfully started on this server
[001.185]   <~~ 220 MailRelayServer ESMTP server ready
[001.185]       We are allowed to connect
[001.185]   ~~> EHLO www12-do.checktls.com
[001.284]   <~~ 250-Hello [142.93.73.156]
                250-DATA
                250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
                250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5
                250 OK
[001.285]       We can use this server
[001.285]   ~~> AUTH PLAIN ********
[001.387]   <~~ 235 Authentication successful
[001.387]       AUTH successful
[001.387]   ~~> MAIL FROM:<test@checktls.com>
[001.490]   <~~ 550 test@checktls.com ... Sender not accepted
[001.490]       Cannot proof email address (reason: MAIL FROM rejected)
[001.490]       Note: This does not affect the CheckTLS Confidence Factor
[001.490]   ~~> QUIT
[001.589]   <~~ 221 Bye
```

When I try to update the connection details in my GMail app on my phone, it keeps saying

```
Email security not guaranteed  
There was a problem setting up security for this account
```

My SMTP server log says

```
2022-08-17 15:40:12 New Client Connected (46.114.140.164 [telefonica.de] -> AbuseIPDB Score: 0)
2022-08-17 15:40:12 SSL connection established for 46.114.140.164
2022-08-17 15:40:12 --> 220 MailRelayServer ESMTP server ready
2022-08-17 15:40:12 Client 0 from 46.114.140.164 Disconnecting
2022-08-17 15:40:13 New Client Connected (46.114.140.164 [telefonica.de] -> AbuseIPDB Score: 0)
2022-08-17 15:40:13 SSL connection established for 46.114.140.164
2022-08-17 15:40:13 --> 220 MailRelayServer ESMTP server ready
2022-08-17 15:40:13 Client 0 from 46.114.140.164 Disconnecting
```

So GMail tries 2 times, establishes a secure connection, and then doesn't react anymore (doesn't even send a 'QUIT' command).

Now to the question: As there's obviously something missing in the communication, I need a communication sample (something like my SMTP server protocol will do fine). Does anybody know where to get it? I searched the web, but can only find simple samples for STARTTLS, which is not what I need now.
Thanks in advance!

Output of the openssl tool:

```
# openssl s_client -connect mrs.dzir.org:465
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mrs.dzir.org
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = mrs.dzir.org
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Aug 16 09:27:26 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Nov 14 09:27:25 2022 GMT
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 20 19:14:03 2021 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 30 18:14:03 2024 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFHjCCBAagAwIBAgISBDQeLzaBb9+bUfozRluuUoZ9MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
MDIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRYwFAYDVQQKEw1MZXQncyBFbmNyeXB0MQswCQYDVQQD
EwJSMzAeFw0yMjA4MTYwOTI3MjZaFw0yMjExMTQwOTI3MjVaMBcxFTATBgNVBAMT
DG1ycy5kemlyLm9yZzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMCK
AiOqNuaIj6pyt2HeQR/RQtxrXJL8uKppf05YFHhFUfJwOXxSDWioxlqn0igps7cO
NDoti4QC30BhsrAWXzewVtrROHStQYBmSOuGbtrLZ/FKMyXw/fH3ev1ObBgKBD3o
e9D1QC36kiqm34WQtCQ5rizcevKerkeuLAlj81SuyRONarWzG44GWjqtN0g9v6Vz
9QbvAqVLWyfgbJqYNpsbju9Sbc1QFpYL7JZ7nwhf+g6F8zWdSqMNXQCoYWMwf3WE
Qrj5lE8QLEbcszmtfYVvl40hOO9qPDdaz+PCXvWmHkktxt+GYi76HJxWYn7jMd0/
Te+zW7aBZ3s2+AxJScMCAwEAAaOCAkcwggJDMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDAdBgNV
HSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAdBgNVHQ4E
FgQUG2PkYn93TKVeB3bXcQejuT/KBmkwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUFC6zF7dYVsuuUAlA
5h+vnYsUwsYwVQYIKwYBBQUHAQEESTBHMCEGCCsGAQUFBzABhhVodHRwOi8vcjMu
by5sZW5jci5vcmcwIgYIKwYBBQUHMAKGFmh0dHA6Ly9yMy5pLmxlbmNyLm9yZy8w
FwYDVR0RBBAwDoIMbXJzLmR6aXIub3JnMEwGA1UdIARFMEMwCAYGZ4EMAQIBMDcG
CysGAQQBgt8TAQEBMCgwJgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWGmh0dHA6Ly9jcHMubGV0c2VuY3J5
cHQub3JnMIIBBAYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSB9QSB8gDwAHYA36Veq2iCTx9sre64X04+
WurNohKkal6OOxLAIERcKnMAAAGCpjGinAAABAMARzBFAiBOeG4tx7GFAeL65wk4
934DXgNrUbkRMalQD27PwPnN3AIhANdIcwJRjJAydZHsin1Wb2QINAcwiay6JOAz
R6HNOnD3AHYARqVV63X6kSAwtaKJafTzfREsQXS+/Um4havy/HD+bUcAAAGCpjGi
xQAABAMARzBFAiBYh3PL5r/CsD+ZUhQ7xUyFuHzV7wqyy/sL1J2vgbn1sQIhAIIV
VF8Th0lP42R0kiUA657yhofIPlBYSHA2umyWQHQYMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IB
AQCxdAHo8/vqiKdV1tw9ErjdY1xR0UgDAOPY2w9RgGZBIjQmfpQU0aqHvTBJetrK
Gjli9++Mg9cLKwsOLBe3r0gOLqwitdbcB9hh1sbUqPjhfjoa7uGBciU6XuRPtzRX
X0p7kQ6QrJvs8+QaZKiliQfMfiG8mzBJTOiTrWyfha4FvfC0BgvP5dnZHa8xY5dM
XJSdg0wQzxA8vI+dCyncqDlIo6ngwaoXqELF90fBT2WsvJfBDf5W8iqM/Iujw0DS
tY1d+cq1QM+7bVNrYrQkPRol0hhCzz7eSlvIp6Bx7jc0UcJq/EvkegoCZ7J4qX+/
EkydQTh73ho5D/28Ny0PgMfE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = mrs.dzir.org
issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4633 bytes and written 424 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: B8346466CC912BE31A603A30F52C3289464D8964107FC8CCCBAEF6B21E6B5FA2
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 7C325FBD4945DEA9F2E6C0236B94CB968580167BAD18BDA3034A2075BF894E40A1FD35E03D3D82E170BF09C5CFC1BC23
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 53 5c 5c 8f 9c 0a ee c8-59 2d 61 ac df c2 61 d1   S\\.....Y-a...a.
    0010 - fb 91 6c 20 44 df 9f 05-93 86 ce b4 29 eb da 65   ..l D.......)..e
    0020 - de f3 97 04 4a 68 72 61-88 a3 7d 7f 13 26 5d 41   ....Jhra..}..&]A
    0030 - 89 15 99 4f ab 6c 86 4a-23 b5 52 cc f6 0b 1c 85   ...O.l.J#.R.....
    0040 - 63 3d c9 98 36 08 ad 58-fe fb d2 9c 74 f0 ca 52   c=..6..X....t..R
    0050 - 73 36 ce d4 41 6d aa 86-53 af 22 ac 42 a7 f6 a9   s6..Am..S.".B...
    0060 - 6d 19 3f ca 2a ec 5a c9-fd 26 6d 88 4e 3d 4c 9b   m.?.*.Z..&m.N=L.
    0070 - 7f d8 ee a0 ad f3 f2 eb-d0 5a d4 76 25 4f 7f 01   .........Z.v%O..
    0080 - ca 2d 50 77 44 fb 62 f3-4d 67 2c dc 00 45 28 74   .-PwD.b.Mg,..E(t
    0090 - 88 10 30 c8 b6 7c 8d bb-bc 24 a7 70 3a 00 26 00   ..0..|...$.p:.&.
    00a0 - da 85 24 04 c2 2a de b4-59 90 ee d8 b9 e7 81 e7   ..$..*..Y.......
    00b0 - ab 9a 06 4c 4b 7b 4e 1d-13 e3 bc a4 13 07 c9 c7   ...LK{N.........
    00c0 - 35 26 8a 45 59 e9 fc a0-ff 7d 30 d6 62 8b 51 21   5&.EY....}0.b.Q!

    Start Time: 1660805781
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 2291062CB8DDF654332636FE85D4A9BB9833B1BE052CA12C26CBBA790D542B35
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 5E7ED4B63AF3D4F1703055F06DCEB9F5B730F1FBC1F738C8AAFABDE702578D0C2F9F6D51D822C59B8C5EA6A1A481C0C1
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 53 5c 5c 8f 9c 0a ee c8-59 2d 61 ac df c2 61 d1   S\\.....Y-a...a.
    0010 - 1e 26 ab 4d c7 7f 14 ae-f8 0c 29 c9 2f 2a e4 c5   .&.M......)./*..
    0020 - 0b d5 61 8a 80 cd 5c 0a-ef 25 17 52 69 6e c0 0c   ..a...\..%.Rin..
    0030 - d6 73 16 2d 70 90 d7 9d-bd ac dc 35 62 f3 9a 33   .s.-p......5b..3
    0040 - ce 7e 33 e2 f7 56 b7 84-de f6 f8 ff 82 fe 7a 9c   .~3..V........z.
    0050 - 4c 68 27 3a 7c 6b 02 44-90 6d 88 d1 97 5d 13 98   Lh':|k.D.m...]..
    0060 - a8 41 f5 3c d2 14 84 62-30 94 f2 fd 1c 1b 42 80   .A.<...b0.....B.
    0070 - 6c c9 10 ce 60 ff 4b 76-c8 e3 7d 49 d0 fe 0b a3   l...`.Kv..}I....
    0080 - 5b 31 c2 77 52 8c 87 17-c3 1b 3d 83 51 2a 12 ed   [1.wR.....=.Q*..
    0090 - c6 7c 0e 07 ba b3 bf ec-ee c3 ee b6 41 6d 0b b5   .|..........Am..
    00a0 - bf 2c fd 1e 05 e4 c3 76-3b 9d 1d 52 a1 2b f2 5e   .,.....v;..R.+.^
    00b0 - 35 f8 a4 56 d1 4c 8f c1-c6 cb 8c 2a 4f a3 fe ad   5..V.L.....*O...
    00c0 - 83 f9 9c dd 31 6f 5a e0-fe d4 c0 70 b0 c7 7b 49   ....1oZ....p..{I

    Start Time: 1660805781
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
220 MailRelayServer ESMTP server ready
```

I added blocking and unblocking the socket before and after enabling crypto, and added a check for the crypto to have been successful. When connection with the openssl tool I can communicate with the server perfectly, but when I try to connect with the GMail app it still says 'email security not guaranteed' and my server's communication log says `New Client Rejected (79.238.153.195 [telekom.de] -> AbuseIPDB Score: 0, TLS could not be established)` (I check the return value of stream_socket_enable_crypto() for this:

```
stream_set_blocking($this->socket, true);
$bOK = stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_SERVER);
$aServer['port']);
stream_set_blocking($this->socket, false);
if (!$bOK) {
    SocketServer::debug('New Client Rejected (' . $ip . ' [' . $ret['data']['domain'] . '] -> AbuseIPDB Score: ' . $ret['data']['abuseConfidenceScore'] . ', TLS could not be established)', '');
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($this->socket, '554 TLS needed', true);
    return false;
}
```

The server's connection log then says:

```
2022-08-18 08:06:04 New Client Rejected (79.238.153.195 [telekom.de] -> AbuseIPDB Score: 0, TLS could not be established)
2022-08-18 08:06:04 --> 554 TLS needed
```

Following ist the class file for the SocketServer and SocketServerClient classes which holds everything to build the connection (simplified as much as possible but still functional):

```
<?php
/**
 * class SocketServer
 * 
 * @author Navarr Barnier
 * @abstract A Framework for creating a multi-client server using the PHP language.
 */
class SocketServer {

    /**
     * @var run
     * @abstract Bool - a boolean to signalize to stop
     */
    protected $run = true;

    /**
     * @var config
     * @abstract Array - an array of configuration information used by the server.
     */
    protected array $config = array();

    /**
     * @var hooks
     * @abstract Array - a dictionary of hooks and the callbacks attached to them.
     */
    protected array $hooks = array();

    /**
     * @var master_socket
     * @abstract resource - The master socket used by the server.
     */
    protected $master_socket;

    /**
     * @var max_clients
     * @abstract unsigned int - The maximum number of clients allowed to connect.
     */
    public int $max_clients = 10;

    /**
     * @var max_read
     * @abstract unsigned int - The maximum number of bytes to read from a socket at a single time.
     */
    public int $max_read = 1024;

    /**
     * @var clients
     * @abstract Array - an array of connected clients.
     */
    public array $clients;

    /**
     * function __construct
     * 
     * @abstract Creates the socket and starts listening to it.
     * @param string - IP Address to bind to, NULL for default.
     * @param int - Port to bind to
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($bind_ip, $port, $domain = '') {
        set_time_limit(0);

        $this->config['ip'] = $bind_ip;
        $this->config['port'] = $port;

        $errno = 0;
        $errmsg = '';

        $set = ['ssl' => [
            'local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' . $domain . '/fullchain.pem',
            'local_pk' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/' . $domain . '/privkey.pem',
            'disable_compression' => false,
            'ssltransport' => 'tlsv1.3'
        ]];
        $context = stream_context_create($set);
        $this->master_socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://{$bind_ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errmsg, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);
        if ($this->master_socket === false) {
            SocketServer::debug("Could not start listening for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port}", '');
            die("Issue Binding\r\n{$errmsg} ({$errno})\r\n");
        }
        stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->master_socket, false);
        SocketServer::debug("Listening for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port} with TLS enabled", '');
        echo "Listenting for connections on {$bind_ip}:{$port} with TLS enabled\r\n";

        pcntl_async_signals(true);
        pcntl_signal(SIGINT, [$this, 'shutdown']); // Call $this->shutdown() on SIGINT
        pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, [$this, 'shutdown']); // Call $this->shutdown() on SIGTERM
    }

    /**
     * function __destruct
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        fclose($this->master_socket);
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            fclose($client->socket);
        }
    }

    /**
     * function hook
     * 
     * @abstract Adds a function to be called whenever a certain action happens. Can be extended in your implementation.
     * @param string - Command
     * @param callback- Function to Call.
     * @see unhook
     * @see trigger_hooks
     * @return void
     */
    public function hook($command, $function) {
        $command = strtoupper($command);
        if (!isset($this->hooks[$command])) {
            $this->hooks[$command] = array();
        }
        $k = array_search($function, $this->hooks[$command]);
        if ($k === FALSE) {
            $this->hooks[$command][] = $function;
        }
    }

    /**
     * function unhook
     * 
     * @abstract Deletes a function from the call list for a certain action. Can be extended in your implementation.
     * @param string - Command
     * @param callback- Function to Delete from Call List
     * @see hook
     * @see trigger_hooks
     * @return void
     */
    public function unhook($command = NULL, $function) {
        $command = strtoupper($command);
        if ($command !== NULL) {
            $k = array_search($function, $this->hooks[$command]);
            if ($k !== FALSE) {
                unset($this->hooks[$command][$k]);
            }
        } else {
            $k = array_search($this->user_funcs, $function);
            if ($k !== FALSE) {
                unset($this->user_funcs[$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * function loop_once
     * 
     * @abstract Runs the class's actions once.
     * @discussion Should only be used if you want to run additional checks during server operation. Otherwise, use infinite_loop()
     * @param void
     * @see infinite_loop
     * @return bool - True
     */
    public function loop_once() {
        $bOK = true;

        // Setup Clients Listen Socket For Reading
        $read[0] = $this->master_socket;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i ++) {
            if (isset($this->clients[$i])) {
                $read[$i + 1] = $this->clients[$i]->socket;
            }
        }

        // Set up a blocking call to socket_select
        $tv_sec = 5;
        $write = $except = null;
        if (@stream_select($read, $write, $except, $tv_sec) < 1) {
            $bOK = false;
        }

        if ($bOK) {
            // Handle new Connections
            if (in_array($this->master_socket, $read)) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i ++) {
                    if (empty($this->clients[$i])) {
                        $this->clients[$i] = new SocketServerClient($this->config['ssl']);
                        if ($this->clients[$i]->connect($this->master_socket, $i)) {
                            $this->trigger_hooks("CONNECT", $this->clients[$i], "");
                        }
                        else {
                            unset($this->clients[$i]);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    elseif ($i == ($this->max_clients - 1)) {
                        SocketServer::debug("Too many clients... :( ");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Handle Input
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i ++) { // for each client
                if (isset($this->clients[$i])) {
                    if (in_array($this->clients[$i]->socket, $read)) {
                        if ($this->config['ssl']) {
                            $input = fread($this->clients[$i]->socket, $this->max_read);
                        }
                        else {
                            $input = socket_read($this->clients[$i]->socket, $this->max_read);
                        }
                        if ($input == null) {
                            $this->disconnect($i);
                        }
                        else {
                            $this->trigger_hooks("INPUT", $this->clients[$i], $input);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->run;
    }

    /**
     * function disconnect
     * 
     * @abstract Disconnects a client from the server.
     * @param int - Index of the client to disconnect.
     * @param string - Message to send to the hooks
     * @return void
     */
    public function disconnect($client_index, $message = "") {
        $i = $client_index;
        SocketServer::debug("Client {$i} from {$this->clients[$i]->ip} Disconnecting", '');
        $this->trigger_hooks("DISCONNECT", $this->clients[$i], $message);
        unset($this->clients[$i]);
    }

    /**
     * function trigger_hooks
     * 
     * @abstract Triggers Hooks for a certain command.
     * @param string - Command who's hooks you want to trigger.
     * @param object - The client who activated this command.
     * @param string - The input from the client, or a message to be sent to the hooks.
     * @return void
     */
    public function trigger_hooks($command, &$client, $input) {
        if (isset($this->hooks[$command])) {
            foreach($this->hooks[$command] as $function) {
                $continue = call_user_func($function, $this, $client, $input);
                if ($continue === FALSE) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * function trigger_hook
     * 
     * @abstract Triggers Hook for a certain command.
     * @param string - Command who's hooks you want to trigger.
     * @param string - The input from the client, or a message to be sent to the hooks.
     * @return void
     */
    public function trigger_hook($command, $input) {
        if (isset($this->hooks[$command])) {
            foreach($this->hooks[$command] as $function) {
                $continue = call_user_func($function, $this, $input);
                if ($continue === FALSE) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * function infinite_loop
     * 
     * @abstract Runs the server code until the server is shut down.
     * @see loop_once
     * @param void
     * @return void
     */
    public function infinite_loop() {
        $test = true;
        do {
            $test = $this->loop_once();
            if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../restart.cmd'))) {
                unlink(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../restart.cmd'));
                $test = false;
                $this->shutdown();
            }
        } while ($test);
    }

    /**
     * function debug
     * 
     * @static
     * @abstract Outputs Text directly.
     * @discussion Yeah, should probably make a way to turn this off.
     * @param string - Text to Output
     * @return void
     */
    public static function debug($text, $dir = '<--', $log = 'communication') {
        global $debug;

        if ($debug) {
            $fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../' . $log . '.log', 'a');
            if (is_array($text)) {
                foreach ($text as $line) {
                    fwrite($fp, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . ((strlen($dir)) ? $dir . ' ' : '') . $line . "\r\n");
                }
            }
            else {
                $lines = explode("\n", $text);
                foreach ($lines as $line) {
                    fwrite($fp, date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . ((strlen($dir)) ? $dir . ' ' : '') . str_replace("\r", '', $line) . "\r\n");
                }
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * function socket_write_smart
     * 
     * @static
     * @abstract Writes data to the socket, including the length of the data, and ends it with a CRLF unless specified.
     * @discussion It is perfectly valid for socket_write_smart to return zero which means no bytes have been written. Be sure to use the === operator to check * for FALSE in case of an error.
     * @param resource- Socket Instance
     * @param string - Data to write to the socket.
     * @param string - Data to end the line with. Specify a "" if you don't want a line end sent.
     * @return mixed - Returns the number of bytes successfully written to the socket or FALSE on failure. The error code can be retrieved with socket_last_error(). This code may be passed to socket_strerror() to get a textual explanation of the error.
     */
    public static function socket_write_smart(&$sock, $string, $crlf = "\r\n") {
        SocketServer::debug($string, '-->');
        $ret = fwrite($sock, $string . $crlf);
        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * function __get
     * 
     * @abstract Magic Method used for allowing the reading of protected variables.
     * @discussion You never need to use this method, simply calling $server->variable works because of this method's existence.
     * @param string - Variable to retrieve
     * @return mixed - Returns the reference to the variable called.
     */
    public function &__get($name) {
        return $this->{$name};
    }

    public function shutdown() {
        $this->run = false;
        SocketServer::debug('Shutting down', '');
        echo "\nShutting down\n";
        $this->__destruct();
        exit(0);
    }
}

/**
 * class SocketServerClient
 * 
 * @author Navarr Barnier
 * @abstract A Client Instance for use with SocketServer
 */
class SocketServerClient {
    /**
     * var socket
     * @abstract resource - The client's socket resource, for sending and receiving data with.
     */
    protected $socket;

    /**
     * var ip
     * @abstract string - The client's IP address, as seen by the server.
     */
    protected $ip;

    /**
     * var hostname
     * @abstract string - The client's hostname, as seen by the server.
     * @discussion This variable is only set after calling lookup_hostname, as hostname lookups can take up a decent amount of time.
     * @see lookup_hostname
     */
    protected $hostname;

    /**
     * var server_clients_index
     * @abstract int - The index of this client in the SocketServer's client array.
     */
    protected $server_clients_index;

    /**
     * function connect
     * 
     * @param resource- The resource of the socket the client is connecting by, generally the master socket.
     * @param int - The Index in the Server's client array.
     * @return bool Connection accepted or not
     */
    public function connect(&$socket, $i) {
        $this->server_clients_index = $i;
        $this->socket = stream_socket_accept($socket) or die("Failed to Accept\n");
        $ip = '';
        $name = stream_socket_get_name($this->socket, true);
        list($ip, $port) = explode(':', $name);
        $this->ip = $ip;

        # Block the connection until the secure connection is established
        stream_set_blocking($this->socket, true);
        $bOK = stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_SERVER);
        stream_set_blocking($this->socket, false);
        if (!$bOK) {
            SocketServer::debug('New Client Rejected (' . $ip . ', TLS could not be established)', '');
            SocketServer::socket_write_smart($this->socket, '554 TLS needed', true);
            return false;
        }
        SocketServer::debug('New Client Connected (' . $ip . ')', '');
        SocketServer::debug('SSL connection established for ' . $ip, '');

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * function lookup_hostname
     * 
     * @abstract Searches for the user's hostname and stores the result to hostname.
     * @see hostname
     * @param void
     * @return string - The hostname on success or the IP address on failure.
     */
    public function lookup_hostname() {
        $this->hostname = gethostbyaddr($this->ip);
        return $this->hostname;
    }

    /**
     * function __destruct
     * 
     * @abstract Closes the socket. Thats pretty much it.
     * @param void
     * @return void
     */
    public function __destruct() {
        fclose($this->socket);
    }

    function &__get($name) {
        return $this->{$name};
    }

    function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->{$name});
    }
}
?>
```

Use it like this ($bind_ip must be the local IP of the machine it runs on):

```
# Create a Server binding to the given ip address and listen to the given port for connections
$sDomain = str_replace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $sMainUrl);
$p1 = strpos($sDomain, '/');
if ($p1 !== false) {
    $sDomain = substr($sDomain, 0, $p1);
}
$server = new SocketServer($aServer['ip'], $aServer['port'], $sDomain);

# Run handleConnect every time someone connects
$server->hook('CONNECT', 'handleConnect');

# Run handleInput whenever text is sent to the server
$server->hook('INPUT', 'handleInput');

# Run Server Code Until Process is terminated
$server->infinite_loop();

# Manage communication classes
$aCommunications = array();

/**
 * function handleConnect
 * 
 * @param $server object Server instance (ignored)
 * @param $client object Client instance
 * @param $input string Input from the connecting client (ignored)
 * @return void
 */
function handleConnect($server, $client, $input) {
    global $aCommunications, $aServer;

    $aCommunications[$client->server_clients_index] = new Communication($aServer['ssl']);
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket, $aCommunications[$client->server_clients_index]->welcome(), $aServer['ssl']);
}

/**
 * function handleInput
 * 
 * @param $server object Server instance
 * @param $client object Client instance
 * @param $input string Input from the connecting client
 * @return void
 */
function handleInput($server, $client, $input) {
    global $aCommunications;

    if (!$aCommunications[$client->server_clients_index]->handleInput($client, $input)) {
        $server->disconnect($client->server_clients_index);
        unset($aCommunications[$client->server_clients_index]);
    }
}
```

The communication after building up the connection is in another file and not needed for this question.

I just tested with Thunderbird (Portable on Windows 10) and it works, but not in GMail on Android. Is this a GMail specific problem? Couldn't find anything useful on that in the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code, including the last changes, works fine if just one setting is changed.

In the class SocketServerClient in the function connect() change the line

```
$bOK = stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_SERVER);
```

to

```
$bOK = stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_SERVER);
```

Both GMail (Android) and Outlook 2019 don't seem to be able to use TLS 1.3.
Outlook 2019 can natively use up to TLS 1.1 and with [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) it can learn TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

The server doesn't answer with TLS on that port.

Using the openssl tool to connect throws the following error, which means that something other than TLS answered:

```
# openssl s_client -connect mrs.dzir.org:465
139891305443776:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```

Using the nc tool to connect gets a plaintext response:

```
# nc mrs.dzir.org 465
220 MailRelayServer ESMTP server ready
```

Comment: From what I see form the checktls.com response (seconds 001.185), TLS is successfully started. In my PHP code I have ```stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_3_SERVER);``` just before the 'SSL connection established for...' log output. Checktls.com says (when checking it) the certificate is valid. So what am I missing here?

If I check with checktls.com without 'Direct TLS', its waiting for an answer and then quits before the TLS connection is established. Therefore I think some command is missing in the communication.

Comment: Oh, btw, as the server is in use, I had TLS disabled over night, sorry. The reaction of the openssl tool now is in the edited question.

Comment: PS: the nc tool now outputs the text only after a while because of ```stream_set_blocking($this->socket, true);``` just before the ```stream_socket_enable_crypto()``` call and back to false after it. It seems that nc doesn't establish a TLS connection and my server doesn't check for that (I must implement a check).

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a simplified example of your code to get any further...